# jQuery to display ANSI graphics

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, graphics

This is my first attempt at a jQuery plugin.  Any tips or comments in regards the the plugin setup would be appreciated.  I'm also looking for a general review over the code itself. I'm wondering if there is a better way to encode the font.  The way I'm doing it now makes it easy to see, read and create the characters, but it's bulky.

One item to note it the font is not yet complete, but most screens/animations have what they need. I should have the font finished out in the next few days.

You can see a working ANSI animated screen [here](http://justinzaun.com/ansi). There is a known issue with IE that prevents this from working. I know the fix, but just haven't gotten doing it yet.

The full font is not listed here as it's too large to post. A full listing is [here](http://justinzaun.com/ansi/js/ansi.js). Only the majority of the font has been removed from the listing below.

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.addClass('ansiScreen');
                var data = $this.data('ansi');
                if (!data) {
                    data = new Object();
                    data.target = $this;
                    data.fontheight = 16;
                    data.fontwidth = 8;
                    data.canvas = $('<canvas width="' + (data.fontwidth * 80) + 'px" height="' + (data.fontheight * 25) + 'px">');
                    $this.append(data.canvas);
                    data.ctx = data.canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                    data.processInterval = null;
                    data.ansi = null;
                    data.ansiCode = null;
                    data.ansiPos = 0;
                    data.fgcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                    data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                    data.bold = false;
                    data.blink = false;
                    data.pos = [0, 0];
                    data.savepos = [0, 0];
                    data.screen = Array();
                    data.last = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                        data.screen.push(Array());
                        for (var j = 0; j < 80; j++) {
                            data.screen[i].push([data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, ' ', false, true]);
                        }
                    }
                    $this.data('ansi', data);
                }
            });
        },
        destroy: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var data = $this.data('ansi');

                // Clean up
                $(window).unbind('.ansi');
                data.tooltip.remove();
                $this.removeData('ansi');
            });
        },
        load: function (ansiUrl) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var me = this;
                $.ajax({
                    'url': ansiUrl,
                    'data': 'text',
                    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
                        jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
                    },
                    success: function(ansiData) {
                        var data = $this.data('ansi');
                        if (data.processInterval != null) {
                            clearInterval(data.processInterval);
                            clearInterval(data.screenInterval);
                        }

                        data.ansi = ansiData;
                        data.ansiPos = 0;
                        data.fgcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                        data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                        data.bold = false;
                        data.blink = false;
                        data.pos = [0, 0];
                        data.savepos = [0, 0];

                        var interval = setInterval(function () {
                            processAnsi.call(me);
                        }, 5);
                        data.processInterval = interval;
                        $this.data('ansi', data);
                        updateDisplay.call(me);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.ansi = function (method) {
        // Method calling logic
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.ansi');
        }
    };

    // Process a byte from teh ansi data
    function processAnsi() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');

        if (data.ansiPos > data.ansi.length)
        {
            clearInterval(data.processInterval);
            return;
        }

        var code = data.ansi.charCodeAt(data.ansiPos) & 0xff;
        data.ansiPos += 1;
        $this.data('ansi', data);

        var display = true;
        if (code < 33 || code > 126)
        {
            switch (code)
            {
                case 0: display = false; break;
                case 10: display = false; cursorStartOfLine.call(this); break;
                case 13: display = false; cursorDown.call(this, 1); break;
                case 27: display = false; ansiCode.call(this); break;
                default: display = true; break;
            }
        }

        if (display) {
            putCharacter.call(this, code);
        }

        updateDisplay.call(this);
    }

    function ansiCode() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');
        if (data.ansiPos > data.ansi.length)
            return '-';

        var valid = /^[0-9;HABCDRsuJKmh]$/;
        var end = /^[HABCDRsuJKmh]$/;
        var char = data.ansi[data.ansiPos];
        var escape = '';
        if (char == '[')
        {
            var stop = false;
            do {
                data.ansiPos += 1;
                var char = data.ansi[data.ansiPos];
                escape += char;
                stop = end.test(char);
            } while (valid.test(char) && !stop)
            data.ansiPos += 1;
        }

        switch(escape[escape.length - 1])
        {
            case 'J': // Clear screen
                if (escape == '2J') {
                    clearDisplay.call(this);
                }
                break;
            case 'A': // Move up
                var lines = parseInt(escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1));
                if (isNaN(lines)) { lines = 1; }
                data.pos[1] -= lines;
                if (data.pos[1] < 0) { data.pos[1] = 0; }
                break;
            case 'B': // Move down
                var lines = parseInt(escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1));
                if (isNaN(lines)) { lines = 1; }
                cursorDown.call(this, lines);
                break;
            case 'C': // Move Forward
                var spaces = parseInt(escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1));
                if (isNaN(spaces)) { spaces = 1; }
                cursorForward.call(this, spaces);
                break;
            case 'D': // Move back
                var spaces = parseInt(escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1));
                if (isNaN(spaces)) { lines = 1; }
                data.pos[0] -= spaces;
                if (data.pos[0] < 0) { data.pos[0] = 0; }
                break;
            case 'H': // Move To
                var codes = escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1).split(';');
                if (isNaN(codes[0])) { codes[0] = 1; }
                if (isNaN(codes[1])) { codes[1] = 1; }
                data.pos[0] = codes[1] - 1;
                data.pos[1] = codes[0] - 1;
                break;
            case 'K': // Clear
                var mode = parseInt(escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1));
                if (isNaN(mode)) { mode = 0; }
                switch (mode)
                {
                    case 2: // clear current line
                        for (var i=0; i< data.screen[0].length; i++)
                        {
                            data.screen[data.pos[1]][i] = [data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, 32, false, true];
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1: // clear start of line
                        for (var i=0; i< data.pos[1]; i++)
                        {
                            data.screen[data.pos[1]][i] = [data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, 32, false, true];
                        }
                        break;
                    case 0: // clear end of line
                    default:
                        for (var i=data.pos[1]; i< data.screen[0].length; i++)
                        {
                            data.screen[data.pos[1]][i] = [data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, 32, false, true];
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case 's': // Save position
                data.savepos[0] = data.pos[0];
                data.savepos[1] = data.pos[1];
                break;
            case 'u': // Restore position
                data.pos[0] = data.savepos[0];
                data.pos[1] = data.savepos[1];
                break;
            case 'm': // Change attrinutes
                var codes = escape.substring(0, escape.length - 1).split(';');
                for (var i=0; i < codes.length; i++) {
                    var code = codes[i];
                    switch (code) {
                        case '0':
                            data.bold = false;
                            data.blink = false;
                            data.fgcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                            break;
                        case '1':
                            data.bold = true;
                            break;
                        case '5':
                            data.blink = true;
                            break;
                        case '30':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' : 'rgb(85, 85, 85)';
                            break;
                        case '31':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(170, 0, 0)' : 'rgb(255, 85, 85)';
                            break;
                        case '32':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(0, 170, 0)' : 'rgb(85, 255, 85)';
                            break;
                        case '33':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(170, 85, 0)' : 'rgb(255, 255, 0)';
                            break;
                        case '34':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(0, 0, 170)' : 'rgb(85, 85, 255)';
                            break;
                        case '35':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(170, 0, 170)' : 'rgb(255, 85, 255)';
                            break;
                        case '36':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(0, 170, 170)' : 'rgb(85, 255, 255)';
                            break;
                        case '37':
                            data.fgcolor = !data.bold ? 'rgb(170, 170, 170)' : 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
                            break;
                        case '40':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
                            break;
                        case '41':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(170, 0, 0)';
                            break;
                        case '42':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 170, 0)';
                            break;
                        case '43':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(170, 85, 0)';
                            break;
                        case '44':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 0, 170)';
                            break;
                        case '45':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(170, 0, 170)';
                            break;
                        case '46':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(0, 170, 170)';
                            break;
                        case '47':
                            data.bgcolor = 'rgb(170, 170, 170)';
                            break;
                        default:
                            $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>Unknown Attribute: ' + code);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>esc[' + escape);
                break;
        }

        $this.data('ansi', data);
        return '';
    }


    // Move the cursor position up a number of lines
    function cursorStartOfLine(lines) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');
        data.pos[0] = 0;
        $this.data('ansi', data);
    }

    // Move the cursor position down a number of lines
    // scroll the screen if needed
    function cursorDown(lines) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');
        var rows = data.screen.length;
        var cols = data.screen[0].length;

        data.pos[1] += lines;
        if (data.pos[1] > data.screen.length - 1) {
            data.pos[1] = rows - 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    data.screen[i][j] = data.screen[i+1][j];
                    data.screen[i][j][4] = true;
                }
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                data.screen[rows-1][j] = [data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, 32, false, true];
            }

        }
        $this.data('ansi', data);
    }

    // Move the cursor position forward a number of columns
    function cursorForward(cols) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');
        data.pos[0] += cols;
        if (data.pos[0] > data.screen[0].length - 1) {
                data.pos[0] = 0;
                cursorDown.call(this,1);
        }
        $this.data('ansi', data);
    }

    // Puts a character on screen
    function putCharacter(charCode) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');
        data.screen[data.pos[1]][data.pos[0]] = [data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, charCode, data.blink, true];
        $this.data('ansi', data);

        // Move forward 1 character
        cursorForward.call(this, 1);
    }

    // Clear the screen
    function clearDisplay() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.screen.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.screen[i].length; j++) {
                data.screen[i][j] = [data.bgcolor, data.fgcolor, ' ', data.blink, true];
            }
        }
        data.pos = [0, 0];
        $this.data('ansi', data);
    }

    // Update the container with the current screen
    function updateDisplay() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');

        for (var i = 0, length1 = data.screen.length; i < length1; ++i) {
            var a = data.screen[i]; // cache object
            for (var j = 0, length2 = a.length; j < length2; ++j) {
                if (a[j][4])
                {
                    data.ctx.save();
                    data.ctx.beginPath();
                    data.ctx.rect (data.fontwidth * j, data.fontheight * i, data.fontwidth, data.fontheight);
                    data.ctx.clip();

                    data.ctx.fillStyle = a[j][0];
                    data.ctx.fillRect (data.fontwidth * j, data.fontheight * i, data.fontwidth, data.fontheight);

                    data.ctx.fillStyle = a[j][1];
                    drawCharater.call(this, a[j][2], [data.fontwidth * j, data.fontheight * i], 1);
                    data.ctx.restore();

                    a[j][4] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        $this.data('ansi', data);
    }


    // Draw a single character at a given location
    function drawCharater(code, location, size) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = $this.data('ansi');

        var template = new Array();
        switch(code)
        {
            case 32:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 48:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]);
                template.push([1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]);
                template.push([1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]);
                template.push([0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 49:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 50:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 51:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 52:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 53:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 54:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 55:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 56:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            case 57:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]);
                template.push([0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
            default:
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                template.push([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
                break;
        }

        for(var y=0; y<16; y++)
        {
            for(var x=0; x<8; x++)
            {
                if (template[y][x] == 1)
                    data.ctx.fillRect(location[0] + x, location[1] + y, 1, 1);              
            }
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a bit more concise syntax. For example, when filling the `data` object in ìnit()`, you could use literal object notation:

```
data = {
  target: $this,
  fontheight: 16,
  fontwidth: 8,
  canvas: $('<canvas width="' + (data.fontwidth * 80) + 'px" height="' + (data.fontheight * 25) + 'px">'),
   // etc.
}
```

Or use `jQuery.extend()`, to add or overwrite properties.

You don't need to reassign the `data` object (`$this.data('ansi', data);`) after changing the the properties of `data`, because it's a reference and all changes have been applied to the object "inside jQuery" already. Example:

```
var $example = jQuery("body");
var data = {}; // Empty object
$example.data("ansi", data); // Assign data
var data = $example.data("ansi"); // get reference
data.test = "hello";
alert($example.data("ansi").test); // Shows 'hello'. No need to call $example.data("ansi", data); before
```

In `destroy()` you call `data.tooltip.remove();`, but I can't seem to see `data.tooltip` ever being set.

You have some duplicate code, that could be refactored into a separate function, such as parsing the integers from the escape sequences.

You should consider moving the actual "business code" parts into separate functions.

The colors should be kept in an array/object instead of assigning them.

(More maybe later.)